# Delimeted insert into excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I would like to insert file lines into excel sheet but it does not care about the formatting, if i paste it manually from clipboard it works.

input.txt
aaaaaaa  1234567 12345678
bbbbbbb 1234567  12345678
ccccccc    1234567 12345678
ddddddd 1234567    12345678

```
string[] exp = File.ReadAllLines("input.log");
for (int i = 0; i < exp.Length; i++)
            {
                //tbDebug.Text += "\r\n" + exp[i];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = exp[i];
            }
```

How can i insert into cell to keep the format like

A       B      C
aaaaaa 1234567 12345678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create one cell. You have to split the string first and then add multiple cells for every line in the log file.